# Copy *changed/new files only* to a DIFFERENT directory?

Tags: rsync

I have two directories that I'd like to keep in sync.

For backup purposes I'd like to run the rsync command such that it will copy new or changed files to a separate USB drive (or another directory) which I can review prior to completing the sync.

In the end I want:

1. original directory
2. backup directory (untouched by this command other than to look to see what's there)
3. separate incremental directory that contains only the new/changed files.

Is this possible?

Comment: Would you accept an answer that doesn't create the intermediate directory but does allow speculative viewing of what would happen if the rsync did run?

Comment: Never mind, I've added an answer that should cover whatever your needs are.

Comment: I just wondered whether you would consider marking my Answer as correct? Some time has passed and it seems like no one else is willing or able to propose a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to see which files will be affected, without seeing the differences between them, you can use the `--dry-run` option to rsync. Let's set up a sandpit for testing:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir -p testing/{a,b}
$ cd testing/
$ touch a/hello a/world
$ ls a
hello
world
$ rsync -rv --append-verify a/ b
$ ls b
hello
world
```

Now perform modifications to the contents of `a`:

```
$ echo 123 > a/hello 
$ touch a/abc
```

Now use `rsync ... --dry-run ...` to see what would happen:

```
$ rsync -rv --append-verify --dry-run a/ b
sending incremental file list
abc
hello

sent 103 bytes  received 22 bytes  250.00 bytes/sec
total size is 4  speedup is 0.03 (DRY RUN)
```

We can see no changes were actually made to `b`:

```
$ ls b
hello
world
$ cat b/hello
$
```

If you need to see the differences between the directories you can use `diff`:

```
$ /bin/diff -aurN a b
diff -aurN a/hello b/hello
--- a/hello 2018-12-13 08:16:23.376761456 +1100
+++ b/hello 2018-12-13 08:16:11.306761686 +1100
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-123
```

If `b` is on a remote box and you need to see the differences, you'll need to create a local copy of `b` and then you can `diff`.

Comment: That's helpful - I'll have to parse the output and run a second script based on that to copy it elsewhere. Wish there was a one-liner rsync command, but that may not exist. I'll keep it open for a bit for other answers to crop up.

Comment: @cryptarch Learned something useful, thks to line-by-line walk thru.

Comment: This is helpful, but I think it does not answer the question. The OP wanted to directly perform the operation not to gather the information needed to do it. I believe a better answer is https://serverfault.com/a/508272/173599.

Answer (score 6):

I believe a better answer is in https://serverfault.com/a/508272/173599. Here I quote the relevant command:

```
rsync -aHxv --compare-dest=folder2/ folder1/ folder3/
```

To compare `folder1` with `folder2` as destination, but copy instead in `folder3`.